# Generate CSV sample iphone app/code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Does anyone have a sample app or some sample code to generate a CSV file on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) will both read and write CSV files on OS X and iOS. It comes with some examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a simple code to generate CSV file :

```
NSArray *csvArray = [myTextView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSString *csvString = [csvArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"csvString:%@",csvString);

// Create .csv file and save in Documents Directory.

//create instance of NSFileManager
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Document Dir: %@",documentsDirectory);

NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.csv", @"userdata"]]; //add our file to the path
[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:[csvString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (file)
```

Comment: This won't handle commas in the data correctly. For example, if you want to encode the data "Gates, Bill" and "Microsoft", it would incorrectly produce the string "Gates, Bill,Microsoft", making it look like there are 3 columns when in fact there are only 2.

Answer (score 4):

Following code I used for generating CSV.

```
   NSMutableString *mainString=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@""];
    for(int i=0;i<[commentArray count];i++ ) {
        NSString *string=[[commentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"cmtName"]; 
        string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\"\""];
        [mainString appendFormat:@"\"%@\"",string];

        string=[[commentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"cmtDesc"];  
        string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\"\""];
        [mainString appendFormat:@",\"%@\"",string];

        string=[[commentArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"cmtType"];
        string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\"\""];
        [mainString appendFormat:@",\"%@\"",string];

        [mainString appendFormat:@",\"%@\"",string];
        [mainString appendFormat:@"\n"];
    }


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Docment.conf"];


    NSData* settingsData;
    settingsData = [mainString dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    if ([settingsData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES])
        NSLog(@"writeok");
```

And for importing CSV you use this

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser