# Save NSArray variable as CSV file with objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, csv

Please may i know how to save a NSArray variable as CSV file using objective-C and Xcode.

I want to save it in: \tmp file

```
NSArray *TArray;
NSMutableArray *Xdata;
NSMutableArray *Ydata;

for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
 [Xdata addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(i/3.14)]];

 [Ydata addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(i*3.14)]];

}

TArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:Xdata, Ydata, nil];
```

So how can i save "TArray" as CSV file ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think storing CSV file in `NSArray` does not mean anything... as CSV file will contain strings only. You can store CSV file in `NSString`.

Please go through my answer in the previous post for storing csvString in `NSString`.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to link my question, but please go through this link, which will give you example...

[Generate CSV sample iphone app/code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308503/generate-csv-sample-iphone-app-code/8308747#8308747)