# How to write results in to NSArray and save it as csv file using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, csv

I'm trying to store my results in NSArray and save it as CSV File using Objective-C but i don't seem to find any solution which is relevant. Please find the below sample code:

```
int a=5,b=10;
int c=b-a;
double d=4.5,e=3.0;
double h=d-e;
NSLog(@"host_port:%f", c);
NSLog(@"host_size:%d", h;
```

I would like to store my values c and h in array and write that to CSV File. Any advise on this would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can store Objects in NSArray, not primitives. CSV, that's just a text (string) with custom format (separator, new lines, etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you store "int" values in an NSMutableArray\* or NSMutableDictionary\*? Chronic problems with JSON data that come in as integers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764391/how-do-you-store-int-values-in-an-nsmutablearray-or-nsmutabledictionary-chr)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate CSV sample iphone app/code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308503/generate-csv-sample-iphone-app-code/8308747#8308747)

Answer (score 0):

*When you ask a question on SO you need to show **effort** - code you've tried, details of what you've read - if you don't you'll get down and close votes (you have one of each as I write this). The code you have included has nothing to do with CSV or arrays, and is not even pasted in valid code (the formats are wrong).*

That said, let's see if you can give you something to get you going.

A CSV file is just plain text, you don't need to use any packages to write one, just standard I/O routines will do the job. You also do not need to store all the values in an array and then output the array, or build up a string version of the whole CSV file and output that, you can output items as they are generated if you wish and it may be more efficient to do so. In your code fragment you only have two values, maybe you intend this to be the core of a loop, and given those we assume you wish the CSV file:

```
host_port,host_size
5,1.5
```

your values have basic types, `int` and `double`, they are not Objective-C object types. Given this you can use the standard C I/O operations to produce your file.

First you may need to obtain the destination file name from the user, assuming this is a GUI app look up `NSOpenPanel` for this. That will give you an `NSURL` from which you can obtain the file path as an `NSString`, and you can convert that into a C string using `NSString` methods.

Now you can enter the C I/O world, to find the documentation on the following functions open the `Terminal` and use the `man` command, e.g. `man fopen` etc.

To create and open for writing the file for writing use `fopen()` passing it the C string pathname you obtained above.

To write the headers and each row of data use `fprintf()`. This takes a format string just like `NSLog()`, but you must remember to explicitly include the line breaks by using `\n` in the format.

When you've finished close the file with `fclose()`.

Now go read the documentation and write your CSV file!

HTH